# IE6 is not updating the style once a class is removed from an element

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm building a website and i'm trying to get it to display correctly under IE6 and as you might guess, it's a lot of work.

I have this CSS style :

```
table.tasks > tbody > tr.finished> td.description
{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

And this html code :

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="description">Blah</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I programmatically add the class "finished" to the <tr> (using jQuery). And the style is updated, the text appears striked. However, when I programmatically remove this same class (still using jQuery) the style is not updated, the text still appears striked.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: You failed to include your jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 does **not** recognise direct children selector(>) so jQuery might be failing to update the styles. Though this is not a good solution. Either you have to remove those children selectors or use a different method for IE6.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing and re-creating the element from scratch .. 
Either way, IE6 is a total lose of your precious development time!! Good luck at it!!